# Check off tabularized lotto numbers automatically

Tags: excel, vba, automation

There is a fundraising lotto in our local pub whereby people pick 6 lotto numbers, and after each Saturday draw any matching numbers are highlighted. This is repeated each week until someone has all 6 of their numbers highlighted and they win the prizemoney.

I have a list of 50 people's lotto numbers in a spreadsheet. Separately, I have each week's lotto numbers in a different table.

I currently go through highlighting them manually. I know I could write a vba script with a loop within a loop within a loop checking each person's number with each result number but that seems very clunky. I can't for the life of me relate a conditional formatting formula applying to each individual number.

Any advice for automation would be gratefully received.

Comment: I'm not quite clear, do people pick a new set of lotto numbers each week or do they stick with the same numbers? Not that it would necessarily change the answer much, just give a better idea of how the data looks. Ideally show some test data.

Comment: They stick with their original pick of 6 numbers and then each week their numbers are gradually crossed off until someone has finally completed their set. I apologise, I'm on a flight with no laptop otherwise I would attach a screenshot of my spreadsheet, but my bored mind wants to find a solution whilst over France!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a slightly different interpretation of your question. To see how it might work out, I put the week number into a cell and used this formula in conditional formatting to see how the results would look after n weeks:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("J2:O"&$H$2+1),A2)
```

So after 4 weeks nobody has won, but after 5 weeks the person in row 19 has won:

[image]

[image]

If you were adding results week by week, you could just use a big enough range to include all the results e.g.

```
=COUNTIF($J$2:$O$20,A2)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, down to the last detail. Im quite proficient at Excel being in accounting, but im a bit green on the finer details of things like conditional formatting. Excellent help, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Conditional formatting formula in B2 is:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,$I$2:$I$7,0))
```

Change the reference `$I$2:$I$7` to wherever your drawn numbers are listed.

Then apply the formatting to all the numbers people have picked.

[image]

Comment: So your formula has b2 in the match, but then the applied to column you have the full table. Does excel change the formula to apply to each cell in the "applies to" range? I presumed this way was a no-go because I would have to type a slightly different "match" formula for every lotto number that every different person picked!

Comment: Yes, because it is a relative reference (there are no $ signs), it will change for each cell. B2 will check B2, B3 will check B3, etc. By default, Excel uses absolute references (with the $ signs) in conditional formatting, maybe that's why your attempts didn't work.

Comment: Tried this answer, and it worked for a list perfectly, however because 6 numbers are added each week and I want them in a table, unfortunately this doesnt work for an array of results. Thankyou though!